# Browser crashes after periodic update of Highcharts series data

Tags: javascript, highcharts, papaparse

I have an application that has a real-time chart.  Every 10-15 seconds, new data is available and the AWS S3 url sent down to the browser over a web socket.

The callback gets the S3 url of the CSV file and papaparse is used to download and process the data.  Checking Chrome dev tools, the javascript object count continues to increase and I'm assuming this has something to do with the browser crashing.  Here's the callback:

Note: initialData is an array with the default series properties including an empty "data" property

```
var shotCallback = function (data) {
                if (hchart.series.length) {
                    for (var i = 0; i <= hchart.series.length - 1; i++) {
                        hchart.series[i].setData([]);
                    }
                    hchart.redraw();
                } else {
                    initialData.forEach(function (item, i) {
                        hchart.addSeries(angular.extend({}, initialData[i]), false);
                    });
                }
                Papa.parse(data.url, {
                    download: true,
                    fastMode: true,
                    worker: true,
                    dynamicTyping: true,
                    skipEmptyLines: true,
                    step: function (results) {
                        if ( ! firstRow) { // first row has column names
                            results.data[0].forEach(function (item, i) {
                                if (i > 0 && i <= initialData.length) {
                                    hchart.series[i - 1].addPoint(item, false);
                                }
                            })
                        }
                        firstRow = false;
                    },
                    complete: function () {
                        hchart.redraw();
                    }
                });
            };
```

This is loading several thousand data points but the performance is quite good.

My question is: when I clear the previous data set, am I doing it correctly by using `.setData([])` or should I be doing it differently?

The browser continues to crash and I'm not sure what to do next.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I was running HighCharts 4.2.5 and upgraded to 5.0.10 and it resolved the problem.  I had run across some posts that there were some memory leaks associated with version 4.